# How to track the flow of execution in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, execution

I have got the flow of execution of a program in eclipse using

```
CTRL + ALT + H
```

but I don't know how to track the flow of execution in netbeans.

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTRL + ALT + H in eclipse is the **Call Hierarchy**.

If you select a method and right click on it you will find it in the context menu.

Go to **Tools > Options > Keymap** and you can set a shortcut for it.